# What does [ ... || ... <- ...] do in this snippet of code?

Tags: erlang

I need your help again, I am trying to understand this piece of erlang code.

```
Line="This is cool".
Lines = [Line || _Count <- lists:seq(1,5)].
```

output is

```
["This is cool","This is cool","This is cool","This is cool","This is cool"]
```

I don't understand the logic behind it printing the required number of times. What does `Line || _*****` means?

Comment: http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/list_comprehensions.html

Comment: In the examples given in the link, [X || X <- [1,2,a,3,4,b,5,6], X > 3].
[a,4,b,5,6] The first X gets it value from X <- [1,2,a,3,4...]. In my case, Line doesn't fetch any value from _**** instead it prints Line, the number of times defined by _******* <- lists:seq(1,5)

Comment: Okay, I think I got it! Just tell me this much, if I use Count instead of _Count, and when I compile, it gives Warning: variable 'Count' is unused but no warnings with _Count?

Comment: _ prefix aware compiler (and people reading the code) that this variable was left intentionally unused (here for documentation purposes), not by some silly mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Since the value of `Line` is not changed in the right hand side of the list comprehension, the value of each element is the same, the value of `Line`.

The right side of the list comprehension is just determining the number of elements.

Comment: Moreover, there is a little hint: `_Count` has underscore prefix because it's value gets unused and thrown away (with such naming compiler will not yell on you).

Answer (score 2):

Look at this piece of code:

```
Line = "This is cool".
Lines = [{Line, Count} || Count <- lists:seq(1, 5)].
```

Here you create a list of tuples of size 2 where first element is constant and the second is taken from the source list of list comprehension. And if you remove an element from the tuple it won't change list's structure.

Answer (score 0):

it can be read like this: **NewListe = [Dosomething || Element <- Liste]**

create a NewListe this way: for each Element of Liste, build a new element with Dosomething.

Step by step  it gives Liste = lists:seq(1,5) = [1,2,3,4,5];

for each Element, just discard the value of element (it is why it is written as _Count) and

Dosomething is only send back the value "This is cool",

and the result is a list of 5 times "This is cool"

["This is cool","This is cool","This is cool","This is cool","This is cool"]

<- is called a generator; after the sign || you may have generators or filters. For example if we imagine that you have a list of different elements and want to get only the printable list items, turned to upper case, you will need a generator:

> X <- ["toto",5,"Hello",atom] **to get each element**

a filter:

> io_lib:printable_list(X) **to select only the printable lists**

and a transformation:

> string:to_upper(X) **to turn to upper case**

all together you have what is expected:

```
1> [string:to_upper(X) || X <- ["toto",5,"Hello",atom], io_lib:printable_list(X)].
["TOTO","HELLO"]
2>
```